# How to get unnamed object instead of an array in case of only one result in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

We have a transformation with Dataweave which processes a list of objects. We get a json response like that:

```
{"hotels": [{
    "name": "Hotel Oslo",
    "propertyCode": "12345",
    "currency": "NOK"
},
{
    "name": "Hotel Stockholm",
    "propertyCode": "12346",
    "currency": "SEK"
}]}
```

However, in the case of only 1 response, we want to have the following response:

```
{"name": "Hotel Stockholm",
"propertyCode": "12346",
"currency": "SEK"}
```

We are generating the response like this:

```
{
hotels: payload.rows map ((row , indexOfRow) -> {
    name: row.content.companyName.content,
    propertyCode: row.content.propertyCode.content,
    currency: row.content.currencyCode.content
})}
```

What should we put as a condition so that we do not get an array in case of 1 result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function makeHotel(row) {
    name: row.name,
    propertyCode: row.propertyCode,
    currency: row.currency
}
---
{
  hotels: payload.rows map ((row , indexOfRow) -> makeHotel(row))
} when ((sizeOf payload.rows) != 1) 
otherwise makeHotel(payload.rows[0])
```

It will give you an empty array on empty input, the simple object for one input and the structure with array when you have more than one input row.

(For test purposes, with a slightly differnt input structure, but the general solution should be clear.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think there is a way to write it once so that I do not need to repeat all the properties? It is only the first line more or less that I do not want to see, not to be a collection